Which game console is in the movie "Invitation to hell"
In film the game is called "Astro Bomber"

Someone can recognize this console/game-hardware?
From movie Invitation to hell



There were hardly any LCD console in the 1970s. Could you specify which one you refer to?

Not a console, my mistake, now I will correct. ASTRO BOMBER LCD was a "single-board" lcd "console" search on google for ASTRO BOMBER LCD to see it

Please supply a pointer. I have no idea what a 'single board LCD' is supposed to be. Searching for 'Astro Bomber LCD' does not supply such. The only somewhat patching is a module for the extreme rare Epoch Game Pocket Computer (mentioned in footnote 1), which was introduced not in the 1970s, but 1980s and AFTER the movie. It also resembles no likeliness to the picture shown.

Consider "LCD" my mistake/error for confusion, I remove the lcd "stuff" from post now

TL;DR: Epoch's "Invader from Space", from ca.1979

Obviously not a real 1980s LCD game, as resolution and colour shown in the first picture is way beyond anything an LCD could have done in 1984 (*1). Also the image shows clear traces of CRT blur. So in no way a handheld game nor LCD at all.
Picture two shows clearly a Epoch (*2) "Invader from Space" (*3), from 1979 (*4), with it's case painted over in light grey or silver (*5):

(Pictures taken from this thruout documented eBay-auction)
It's graphics were great for its time but in no way like seen in picture one. Also graphics were fixed monochrome LED or VFD (*6) elements, modified by a coloured filter bars, nicely visible in this video. He also mentions the display quality (maybe ignore his generic musings).

(Pictures taken from this very detailed report)
The Retro Arcadia blog just recently featured a very detailed recollection of time and game, filled with very good pictures including one made to show the colour mask. It turned the light blue elements into dark blue, yelowish and redish aliens :))

(Pictures taken from the same report)
The parts shown in the third picture seem to be the shell of (the same or another copy) the game filled with random parts, which seem to me as being from (mains) power electronics.


i'm not refer to console of this movie, but to another lcd console of 70's.

There were hardly any LCD console during the 1970s. The first notable one, MB's Microvision might barely qualify by being introduced for Christmas 1979. The Nintendo's well known Game&Watch series debut in 1980 and any clone/follow up accordingly later.

*1 - The Film was published in 1984, so any prop uses must be of 1983 origin, at latest. At that time graphical LCD were barely making their debut in B&W, no colour and especially not at such range and detail.
It seems like a classic example of looking back with today's tech in mind, imagining the past as the same, just a bit less detailed :))
Resolutions like shown in the first picture only appeared in the second half of the 1980s (see here), and only as B&W. It wasn't until the 1990s that any colour LCD games would appear - still with way less brightness (or better darkness) and less resolution than shown:

Atari Lynx in 1989
Sega Game Gear in 1990
GBC - which many may have in mind for this topic- as late as 1998

A worthy side note here might be Epoch's own "Game Pocket Computer" (Wiki). It does represent top end portable game console when introduced in 1984 - still less than a 1/20th of what picture shows and no colour at all. It was cartridge based system with 75x64 b&w display, two Ki Ram, two build in games and a Z80 inspired microcontroler ... sounds almost as if Nintendo engineers liked it and found 5 years later a way to updated the tech and make the company fortune :))
[And i'm digging already way too deep into that topic :))]
*2 - The game was developed and produced by Epoch in Japan. They also made OEM versions for various game publishers, like Grandstand in the UK. The product was from the start designed to be sold as OEM in different markets. Most notably by the case itself having no obvious brand or language specific markings moulded in. Everything that may differ by brand/language is printed on. This preparedness is also true for box and documentation layout/design, where even translated versions are mostly a search&replace action :)

Invader from Space as sold under the Epoch brand in the US
*3 - Sometimes using a different name as well.
*4 - Grandstand introduced the game in 1980 in the UK and New Zealand
*5 - Ofc, there could as well have been an OEM version using a grey/silver colours plastic, just I'm not aware of any. Also repainting is a common way to make film props appear different. Hard to tell if there is any writing beside the buttons. Maybe other scenes could provide a better view?
But what's quite notable is that the 'screen' does not bear any game or brand name on top or bottom, which does shout loud 'modified'.
*6 - While blue(ish) LED are around since the mit 1970s, It may be more likely a VFD, a display type quite common around 1980, providing a good brightness. Hard to decide without a more close up view.

+1 — the first picture really looks like an 8-bit Atari game, the screen structure is reminiscent of display-list setups typical on that platform. The font is typical of 8-bit games too, similar to this one (from Deathball 2000 on the Spectrum, but the picture doesn’t look like something from the Spectrum). The “Galatic missles” typos are also typical of a certain category of 8-bit games ;-).

@StephenKitt could quite well be, after all, it was the most versatile system, but I've been a bit put off by the 'ASCII' style borders (most notable middle vertical bars as border) in general and more so by combining them as single height with double height characters in the same scan line. Of course this is possible by adding 'half character' glyphs, but that seems a unusual afford when not smoothing out  borders at the same time. The whole picture itches me.

Light blue LED elements?  This is way to early for anything we'd call a blue LED. My guess is it had a miniature incandescent bulb to have that much color range. NVM, looks like it was a VFD backing it. Which explains the color.

@davolfman I might be wrong, but I don't have any Invaders to take apart. Still, blue LED are around since the mid 1970s. What you may refer to is the modern development of very bright blue LED - as brightness relative to other types has been the major issue. Not just for blue, but general. Back in the days combining various colours in a front panel was hard as a faint green doesn't work great with bright red and so on.

@Raffzahn Given the retroarcadia article mentions ad copy talking about a 'flourescent display' a VFD or even EL display is much more likely.  Before '94 blue LEDs just weren't a thing you found in consumer products, or even any products.  The choices were red, green, and yellow.

@davolfman Already changed that part to include possibility of VFD.

I'm pretty sure it's VFD.  I had the Radio Shack version of this game and is was VFD. The Cosmic 1000 Fire Away.  The linked article confirms VFD for that version at least.
